# Show that $a^{p+1\over 4}$ solves the equation $x^2 ≡ a \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let  $p \equiv3 \pmod 4$   be a prime number, and let $1 \le a\le p − 1$ be a
quadratic residue. Show that $a^{p+1\over 4}$  solves the equation $x^2 ≡ a \pmod p$.

I know that if $(a,n)=1$ and $p\ge 3$ then $x^2\equiv a \pmod p$ $\iff$ $a^{p-1\over 2}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. I am trying to apply it here but I can't seem to do it.

$(a^{p+1\over 4})^2=a^{p+1\over 2}$. $a$ is quadratic residue modulo p and therefore $a^{p-1\over 2}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. How can I, maybe, show that $a^{p+1\over 2}\equiv a^{p-1\over 2}\equiv 1 \pmod p$? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh I forgot $p$ is 3 modulo 4.

Comment: I said that $a^{p+1\over 2}=a\cdot a^{p-1\over 2}\equiv a$, but then, I don't use the fact that $p$ is 3 mod 4. What is wrong if so?

Comment: Now that you have reached $a^{(p+1)/2}\equiv a$, it's over!  We then need $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, but only to make sure that $(p+1)/4$ is an integer.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $a$ is a quadratic residue, so there is some $x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$, note that $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Since $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$, we know that $\frac{p+1}{4}$ is an integer.

Then $[\,a^{(p+1)/4}\,]^2 = a^{(p+1)/2} = a\cdot a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv a\cdot 1 \equiv a \bmod p$ as required